# Java Primefaces Error de conexion

Tags: java, tomcat

Estoy utilizando primefaces para el desarrollo de una aplicacion, a la hora de realizar las pruebas en mi server local todo funciona ok, pero al subirlo a tomcat y loguearme en la aplicacion me genera este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi archivo context

```
<Resource   name="jdbc/xxx"
            auth="Container"
            factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            minimumIdle="5"
            minPoolSize = "3"
            maximumPoolSize="10"
            connectionTimeout="300000"
            driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
            jdbcUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxxx;databaseName=xx;instance=xxx;sendStringParameterAsUnicode=false;prepareSQL=2;"
            dataSource.implicitCachingEnabled="true"
            dataSource.user="xxx"
            dataSource.password="xxx"
            connectionTestQuery="Select 1"
/>
```

Que me podra estar generando este error

Comment: Por favor muestra el código donde intentas obtener el pool de conexiones. Asegúrate de también incluir tus sentencias de `import` porque puede que allí esté la causa del problema

Comment: Gracias amigo ya lo resolvi el problema es que al desplegar el war en el server no esta borrando los archivos existentes dejaba unas librerias que ya no utilizaba, replegue el proyecto y desplegue nuevamente